# "In the 1970s, Viking space probes may have etc." - help for understanding

Tags: grammaticality

I've read in the biology book the following sentence:

> In the 1970s,Viking space **probes** may have picked up some microbes that
>   emitted CO2."

I'm not sure if this sentence is grammatically correct because the word probes should be in the past simple tense rather than in present simple tense. Am I right or it's grammatically correct?

Comment: When I read the question title, I thought it would be about how the Vikings could have had space probes.

Comment: And you had to ask a question before spending 1 second googling `define:probe`. **SO**: *Space probes* are the opposite of *anal probes* which are used by aliens and not vikings.

Comment: Seriously now, your question should read "Am I right or _is it_ grammatically correct?"

Comment: It makes me think of another word, `scout`, that is used for both "what he *is*" and "what he *does*".  A probe (noun) is something that probes (verb). The *plural noun* looks like the present-tense verb. And the singular noun looks like the infinitive verb. Personally, I think the opposite use of -s helps disambiguate, helping to take apart complex sentences more quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on [Wikipedia -here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_probe)

There is a scientific instrument which called **space probe** - is a robotic spacecraft that leaves Earth orbit and explores space". (wiki)

Answer (score 30):

Your example is using **probes** as a noun.

A **probe** is a scientific instrument for analysis and measurement, e.g. a **surgical probe**.

Comment: To clarify: **probes** can also be a verb, but it is not in this case.

Comment: Should your "i.e." be an "e.g."? :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, it should - "surgical probe" is an example, it's not another way of saying "A probe is a scientific instrument for analysis and measurement".

Comment: I think "probe" is not only an instrument, but also a sample you get for some examination (e.g. "tissue probe")

Comment: I think it's generally thought that a **probe** is the instrument that gets you a **sample**, **specimen**, or **observation**